# Displaying AJax response with Jquery in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an ajax form that posts to a php page, which processes the form, then posts the data to mysql and then returns the data to the console.

Since I am really new at this, I don't know how to get it to display the data on the page in a `<li>` or `<div` for each new record that is returned, just like this script does: http://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-add-delete-record/

This is the data that is returned in the console:

```
Object {type: "success", message: "Your message has been sent, thank you.", record: Object}
message: "Your message has been sent, thank you."
record: Object
account_number: "1234567812345678"
balance: "1234"
bank_name: "test name"
customer_id: "12345"
id: 49
monthly: "123456"
```

This is the current script that brings it to the console:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('form.quform').Quform({
    successStart: function (response) {
      console.log(response);  
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Take a look at the post : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
and the get method : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
of jQuery for posting to php through ajax and getting data through ajax in jQuery.

Comment: @imsiso its not a jquery feature, its an ajax jquery/php script for forms.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('form.quform').Quform({
        successStart: function (response) {
            var r = response.record;
            var html = '<li>Acct#: ' + r.account_number + '</li><li>Balance: ' + r.balance + '</li><li>Bank: ' + r.bank_name + '</li><li>Customer#: ' + r.customer_id + '</li>';
            $("#ulID").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @imsiso please don't write `+1` in the comments section. If you want to appreciate the answer just upvote it no need to mention :)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - maybe you are right. But I'm asking you would you put a comment like this:  `-1 - because your question/answer has the following problem : ...`?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - But I will do it whether I think its (good`+1`) or (bad`-1`). **(:**

Comment: If you have a special reason for upvoting, like you consider the answer especially clever, it's OK to put it in a comment. But if it's just because it's a good answer, that's assumed and no need to comment.

Comment: I just tried it, it stops the ajax from working, it takes you to the post page when you hit submit instead of staying on the page and getting the result

Comment: Sounds like something needs to use `event.preventDefault` to disable form submission when using AJAX. I'm not familiar with the `Quform` plugin, so I don't know how to do it. If it's for doing AJAX forms, I'm surprised it doesn't do that automatically.

Comment: When I take off the extra `});` the ajax begins to work again, but the data still does not display on the page. I'm pretty sure this has to has to be on the page: `<div id="#ulID"></div>` for it to work, but I tried it with it and without it. I also tried it just `<li id="#ulID"></li>` also.